# Where does this phrase "Bahujana sukhaya bahujana hitaya cha" appear?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, shloka

This wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahujana_sukhaya_bahujana_hitaya_cha) mentions it as an aphorism enunciated in Rigveda. Is this phrase a part of a verse in the rigveda? Does rigveda mention any verse that conveys the same meaning and is same in wordings also? From what i know this phrase was used by Buddha and has no vedic connection. Well verses with similar meaning do occur in vedas but wordings are different(and so different "subjective" interpretations).